# Prove the determinant is the product of its diagonal entries

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that the determinant of an upper triangular matrix is the
product of its diagonal entries.

What I have so far:

We will prove this by induction for an $n \times n$ matrix. For the case of a $2 \times 2$ matrix, let $A= \left( \begin{array}{cc}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
0 & a_{22}  \end{array} \right)$. So $\det(A)=a_{11}a_{22}$ and the statement is true for the case of a $2 \times 2$ matrix.

Now suppose that this statement is true for an $n \times n$ matrix. We will show that it also is true for an $(n + 1) \times (n + 1)$ matrix. Let $A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1(n+1)}\\
0 & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2(n+1)} \\
\vdots & \cdots &  & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & a_{(n+1)(n+1)}\end{array} \right)$.

I don't know what to do after this.

Comment: In what way do you usually calculate the determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix?

Comment: Just expand this determinant by last row and then use your induction hypothesis.

Comment: Do you use the Laplace expansion (using minors) or permutations?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using the cofactor expansion along the first column we get 
$$|A|=(-1)^{1+1}a_{11} \left |\begin{matrix} a_{22}&a_{23} & \cdots & a_{2(n+1)} \\
                                 0 &a_{33} & \cdots & a_{3(n+1)} \\
                                \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
                                0 & 0 & 0 & a_{n+1n+1}
                 \end{matrix}\right |$$ (Note that remaining terms in the expansion are zero.)

Using the induction hypothesis (you know det of the $n\times n$ matrix), we get

$|A|$=$a_{11}a_{22}a_{33}\cdots a_{n+1n+1}$

Comment: Why other terms are 0? Edit: it is because $a_{ij}$ term is 0.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Laplace expansion to finish the induction. If you take the minor $A_{12}$ for example, you'll get the determinant of an upper triangle matrix with top-left entry $0$, which by induction is $0$. The only minor of the top row which is not $0$ is $A_{11}$.

[edit] Used the notation for minors found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_%28linear_algebra%29).