# Exercise 7, Section 5.3 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, proof-writing, determinant

> An $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is called triangular if $A_{ij} = 0$ whenever $i\gt j$ or if $A_{ij}=0$ whenever $i\lt j$. Prove that the determinant of a triangular matrix is the product $A_{11} A_{22}\dotsb A_{nn}$ of its diagonal entries.

**My attempt:** WLOG suppose $A$ is upper triangular matrix i.e. $A_{ij}=0$, if $i\gt j$. By theorem 2 section 5.3, $\text{det}(A)=\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}(\text{sgn}\sigma )A(1,\sigma(1))\dotsb A(n,\sigma(n))$. Then $(\text{sgn}\sigma )A(1,\sigma(1))\dotsb A(n,\sigma(n))\neq 0$, if $A(1,\sigma(1))\neq 0,…,A(n,\sigma(n))\neq 0$. Which implies $1\leq \sigma(1),…,n\leq \sigma(n)$. Since $n\leq \sigma(n)$, we have $n= \sigma(n)$. Since $\sigma$ is injective and $n-1\leq \sigma(n-1)$, we have $n-1= \sigma(n-1)$. Similarly $i=\sigma(i)$, $\forall i\in J_n$. So $\sigma=I$, identity map on $J_n$. Thus $\text{det}(A)$ $=\sum_{\sigma}(\text{sgn}\sigma )A(1,\sigma(1))\dotsb A(n,\sigma(n))$ $=(\text{sgn} I )A(1,1))\dotsb A(n,n)$ $= A(1,1))\dotsb A(n,n)$. Hence $\text{det}(A)= A(1,1))\dotsb A(n,n)$. **Is my proof correct?**

**Potential approach:** if $\sigma(i)\neq i$, for some $i\in J_n$, then show $A(k,\sigma(k))=0$, for some $k$. I can’t make any meaningful progress, because I think it’s really thought provoking.

**Approach(3):** [Here](https://youtu.be/U5v2H61tZuM) is an alternative (but clever) solution, though it uses result from section 5.4. Which is, suppose we have an $n \times n$ matrix of the block form $\begin{bmatrix}A &B\\0&C\end{bmatrix}$, where $A\in M_{r\times r}(K)$, $C\in M_{s\times s}(K)$, $B\in M_{r\times s}(K)$ and $0\in M_{s\times r}(K)$, then $\text{det} \begin{bmatrix}A &B\\0&C\end{bmatrix}=\text{det}(A)\cdot \text{det}(C)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove using Leibniz formula that the determinant of a upper triangular matrix is equal to product of its diagonals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3569822/how-to-prove-using-leibniz-formula-that-the-determinant-of-a-upper-triangular-ma) (same proof)

Comment: Compare your attempt also with the standard solutions, given at this site, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1243237/prove-the-determinant-is-the-product-of-its-diagonal-entries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't follow your proof so I won't comment on whether or not it is correct, but I have never explicitly used this definition of the determinant to prove any of it's properties, and I always suggest you look for other ways first.

As to how I would solve the problem, I would just use induction on $n$. Indeed, let $U = \begin{bmatrix}a&x_{1\times(n-1)}\\0_{(n-1)\times1}&B_{(n-1)\times(n-1)}\end{bmatrix}$ be upper triangular, where $x$ is any vector, and $B$ is any upper triangular matrix. The determinant of $U$ is then $ det(U) = a*det(B)$, which you can see by expanding the determinant along the first column full of zeros (you can use the definition of the determinant here if you want to be fully transparent in your proof).

Comment: determinant of $\begin{bmatrix}a&*\\0&B\end{bmatrix}$ is $a*det(B)$?

Comment: Ah, I see why this might not be clear. Let me rewrite the matrix as $\begin{bmatrix}a&x_{1\times (n-1)}\\0_{(n-1)\times 1}&B_{(n-1)\times (n-1)}\end{bmatrix}$, where $x$ is any vector, and $B$ is upper triangular.

Comment: Yup. Now it makes sense. Proving special case $\text{det}(U)=a \cdot \text{det}(B)$ is relatively easy compared to $\text{det} \begin{bmatrix}A &B\\0&C\end{bmatrix}=\text{det}(A)\cdot \text{det}(C)$. As you suggested, expansion of $\text{det}(U)$ by cofactors of $1$st column, is the most efficient way to prove $\text{det}(U)=a \cdot \text{det}(B)$.